# How to fix 400 bad request using curl and discord api (php)

Tags: php, api, curl, discord

Whenever I try this it replies with "400 bad request"

I've tried adding a client id but I'm not exactly sure how to get that

```php
$url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/science';
$data = json_decode($response);

$ch = curl_init();
$json = array(  "channel_id" => $data->channel->id,
                "channel_type" => $data->channel->type,
                "client_performance_cpu" => 48,
                "client_performance_memory" => 833620,
                "client_send_timestamp" => time(),
                "client_track_timestamp" => time(),
                "client_uuid" => $data->channel->id,
                "code" => $_GET["invite"],
                "destination_user_id" => null,
                "guild_id" => $data->channel->id,
                "invite_type" => "Server Invite",
                "inviter_id" => $data->inviter->id,
                "location" => "Join Guild Modal",
                "resolved" => "true",
                "size_online" => $data->approximate_presence_count,
                "size_total" => $data->approximate_member_count,
                "type" => "resolve_invite",
                "token" => $_GET["token"]
                );
$payload = json_encode($json);
echo $payload;

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array('Authorization: ' . $_GET["token"]),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $json
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload)
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<br/><br/>" . $response;
```

(data is defined it's just on another part of my code)

I want it to accept the invite

Comment: Without knowing the data there's no way to reproduce it. But one potential issue I see, is that you are using the length of `$payload` for `Content-Length` but sending the raw `$json`. So in my eyes, should be `strlen($json)`.